# c# sort list of connected items into multiple lists

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting, tree

It is possible to sort list of objects into multiple groups of interconnected objects that has ref to each other?

Model:

```
public class Item
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public List<Item> ConnectedItem {get;set;}
}
```

The data:

```
    public void Data()
    {
        Item One = new Item() {};
        Item Two = new Item() { };
        Item Three = new Item() { };
        Item Four = new Item() { };
        Item Five = new Item() { };
        Item Six = new Item() { };
        Item Seven = new Item() { };
        Item Eight = new Item() { };
        Item Nine = new Item() { };
        Item Ten = new Item() { };

        One.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>(){Two,Three, Five};
        Two.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { One, Five };
        Three.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { Five, Two };
        Four.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { One, Two };
        Five.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { Four, One, Two ,Three };

        Six.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { Eight };
        Seven.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { Eight };
        Eight.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { Six };

        Nine.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { Ten };
        Ten.ConnectedItem = new List<Item>() { Nine};

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>(new List<Item>() {One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten });


    }
```

What I want to archive is a list of list of interconnected items

-Collection1
----One,Two,Three,Four,Five

-Collection2
----Six,Seven,Eight

-Collection3
----Nine,Ten

```
        List<List<Item>> sortedList = new List<List<Item>>()
        {
            new List<Item>() {One, Two,Three,Four,Five},
            new List<Item>() {Six,Seven,Eight},
            new List<Item>() {Nine,Ten},
        };
```

Comment: I think you need to elaborate on what exactly qualifies an element for inclusion into one of these collections. There is very likely a graph theoretic algorithm for determining this efficiently, but without specifying precise requirements, it will be hard for people to help you.

For that matter, what you have tried thus far? You know the problem better than we do, which part of it is tripping you up?

Speculating, this looks like you are trying to find the *transitive closure* of connections. There are efficient ways to calculate that.

Comment: What qualifies for inclusion is the reference on each ConnectedItem property. If elements are linked than it would have a reference to another element. 
I tried to write a recursive method but hit a brickwall.
Any help is  appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to find the connected components of the graph that your model implies. The connected components can be found by doing [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) from one node, and after the DFS is completed, you go on to find a node that is not already found. I Suppose you have all Items in an Array or List `L`; Also I add a Visited property to Item.

Now you have a directed graph (Item1 might point to Item2 while Item2 does not point to Item1). Apparently, what you're looking for is the connected components of the graph obtained by removing the directions on links.

```
List<List<Item>> components = new List<List<Item>>();
for (int i = 0; i < L.Count; i++)
{
    if (L.Visited) 
        continue;
    var component = new List<Item>();
    DFS(L[i], component);
    components.Add(component);
}
```

and the method DFS:

```
static void DFS(Item item, List<Item> component)
{
    if (component.Contains(item))
        return;
    component.Add(item);
    item.Visited = true;
    foreach (var i in item.ConnectedItems)
    {
         if (!i.Visited)
             DFS(i, component);
    }
    foreach (var i in L)
    {
        if (!i.Visited && i.ConnectedItems.Contains(item))
            DFS(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: When should L.Visited = true be inserted?

Comment: Got it, Thank you so much!

Comment: oops. Thanks, I improved it.